# pug/jade refer to property by name

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to check if some property names are passed to the template based on a preset array:

```
- socialNames = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram']
each socialName in socialNames
    - social = this[socialName]
    if social 
        a(href=social.url)
            div
                img.ug-profile-socials-
icon(src=chrome.extension.getURL('public/socials/'+ social + '.png'))
            div
                span.ug-profile-socials-followers !{social.followers}
```

The social = this[socialName] part is just the way I was expecting it to work, but it obviously does not.

Comment: Can you provide more details to understand what are you expecting 'this' to be here?

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `this` to refer to individual items in the array. You can directly reference the array items using the variable you mentioned in your `each statement` ( `socialName` in your case ):

```
- socialNames = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram']
each socialName in socialNames
    // - social = this[socialName]
    social = socialName
    a(href=social.url)
        div
            img.ug-profile-socials--icon(src=chrome.extension.getURL('public/socials/'+ social + '.png'))
        div
            span.ug-profile-socials-followers !{social.followers}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that pug uses `locals` to refer to the passed arguments:

```
- var social = locals[socialName]
if social
    a(href=social.url)
        div.ug-profile-socials-icon
            img(src=chrome.extension.getURL('public/socials/'+ socialName + '.png'))
        div.ug-profile-socials-followers
            span !{social.followers}
```